# ActiveRecord query with named scope returns wrong id for associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Models code:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :product_groups
  belongs_to :accessible_fields_group

  named_scope :sort_by_priority, :joins => :accessible_fields_group, :order => "priority ASC"
end

class ProductGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

I've got something strange with querying with named_scope by associated object:

```
>> ProductGroup.last.products.map(&:id)
=> [11, 10]
>> ProductGroup.last.products.sort_by_priority.map(&:id)
=> [1, 2]  #<= WHY?
```

Why in second case I've got wrong ids? Any ideas? Generated sql query is good and it returns right ids (10, 11).

I'm using rails 2.3.11, mysql db, ruby ee.

Comment: what does `ProductGroup.last.products.sort_by_priority` return?

Comment: Try ProductGroup.find(the_id_you_want_to_check).products...

Comment: i'd suspect `joins`. Maybe `map(&:id)` returns products' associated objects ids, because it is fooled by the join query ? I don't know well rails 2, so dunno

Comment: @nash, it returns an array of Products, just like ProductGroup.last.products, but of course it's sorted. The problem is that each Product in this array have incorrect id.

Comment: @tokland, Of course it returns the same wrong ids [1,2], problem isn't here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**the result from `ProductGroup.last.products.sort_by_priority` are not database records**
that's why the IDs are not corresponding to database record IDs..

**Do this instead**:

```
ProductGroup.last.products.sort_by_priority.all.map(&:id)
```

**If you're using Rails >= 3.0** this should also work:

```
ProductGroup.last.products.order(:by => :priority).map(&:id)
```

Answer (score 1):

what does

```
ProductGroup.last.products.sort_by_priority.class
```

return?  it is probably not an ActiveRecord::Relation object

Comment: `?> ProductGroup.last.products.class`  
`=> Array`

Comment: `>> ProductGroup.last.products.sort_by_priority.class`  
`=> ActiveRecord::NamedScope::Scope`

Comment: @icem that answers your question! the ids you're seeing in the second call are not IDs ActiveRecord "records" , but the IDs of Scopes